# WebGL animation is flickering back to inital state

Tags: javascript, animation, webgl, shader, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to move a marker on a map with WebGL.

To do that I send 2 vertex attributes and a uniform to the vertex shader : a_position, a_next_position, and u_completion.

In the shader I compute current position as:
    vec2 current_pos = a_pos + u_completion * (a_next_pos - a_pos);

I only update the vertex attributes every second, but I update the uniform on every draw call so that there is a smooth transition between marker positions.
The u_completion value is computed in js in a requestAnimationFrame loop as:
    completion = (now-lastRefresh)/1000;

The problem:
This almost works, but near the end of a transition, the marker is displayed in its initial position for a split second.
I suspect this is because the completion is reset to 0 before the vertex attributes is updated. How can I avoid that? I'm a beginner at webgl.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: hey sorry at that time I didn't know which was the relevant code in hundreds of lines so could not post it. in the end I solved it so I think I can delete the question